# Unwanted break in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

in this [image]

you can see two divs that they are ok in large screens.
but when i resize them to sm-screen left div will jump down. I want that in all types 2 divs be beside eachother. I'm using right to left direction version of bootstrap. can it be the reason?
This is my code:

```
<div class="row clearfix">

<div class="col col-md-10">
<!--Whatever-->
</div>

<div class="col col-md-2">
<ul class="left">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

css

```
.left
{
list-style:none;
border:2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No RTL version is not the reason.
When You write `col-md-10` you have devoted 10 columns to the div in medium screen,and this division works in large & medium screens,but meaningless in small & xSmall.

If you want your division mean in every kind of screens you should use `col-xs-n`.
So the answer of your question is using `col-xs` instead of `col-md`.

Answer (score 1):

Use xs instead of md

```
<div class="col col-xs-10">
```